# Melhor maneira para implementar Balança Toledo Prix 4Uno?

Tags: c#, dll

Boa tarde, adquiri uma balança toledo Prix 4Uno com comunicação via ethernet.

Gostaria de saber se existem exemplos em C# para implementar a comunicação com ela, ou se é somente via software MGV 6.

Qualquer ponta pé inicial já é uma grande ajuda.

**EDIT:**
**Encontrei vários links úteis que me auxiliaram na implementação**

1. Canal do Youtube da fabricante, onde serão encontrados tutoriais de como efetuar a pré-configuração da balança:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fG5DsE9-jeE&list=PLge9BfwMSPNmEpeZ6r0LjqkGQNU_7VqtA
2. Layout do arquivo .txt que será gerado para que o MGV6 importe os itens: https://www.toledobrasil.com.br/help/mgv6/v1_6_/Html_Pages/arquivos_de_cadastro.html
3. Exemplo de como ficaria a tela de exportação completa:
   http://conhecimento.alterdata.com.br/ar/kblive.php?action=showEntry&data=4471
4. Layout do Código de Barras gerado pela balança. Este é necessário para mais tarde dar entrada nas informações pelo sistema:
   https://www.toledobrasil.com.br/help/mgv6/v1_6_/Html_Pages/tipocodigobarras.html

Comment: O ideal é perguntar ao fabricante.

Comment: tem documentação da interface dela ?

Comment: @Renan já vi no site da fabricante e ja perguntei, os mesmos não tem essa informação.

Comment: Tem documentação, porém não auxilia em nada o desenvolvimento. Pelo que estou vendo, tenho que gerar um arquivo de texto p/ importação pelo software que vem junto com a mesma, por hora não encontrei uma forma de fazer direto pelo meu software.

Comment: @RenanValentim se o fabricante não sabe, algo de errado não está certo. Seria como eu te vender um carro e não saber te dizer se o câmbio é automático. Nesse caso, sinto muito, mas você está a desbravar terreno inexplorado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cheguei a dar uma olhada no manual dela: http://www.sotomano.com/produtos/arquivos/prix4uno-618.pdf

Não acho que seja necessário você desenvolver um software pra comunicar com a balança, sendo que o fabricante já disponibiliza um para isso.

Como a balança funciona imprimindo etiquetas com o código de barras, o sistema de vendas só precisa ler a etiqueta e calcular a quantidade, nada mais.

Na parte cadastral dos itens, só é necessário exportar as informações em um arquivo de texto e transferir para a balança pelo software do fabricante.

**Edit:**

Há um tópico aqui: http://www.vbmania.com.br/index.php?modulo=forum&metodo=abrir&id=357291 que pode te ajudar com o layout.

E, pelo que li aqui: http://www.sipsistema.com.br/atualizacao/Manual_MGV5_Op.pdf o arquivo de texto fica na raiz do software, acho que já deve ter o modelo de como deve ser gerado.

Comment: Exatamente, preciso apenas do layout dos arquivos txt para gerar pelo meu software e fazer a carga p/ a balança via MGV 6 (Software distribuido pela fabricante). Uma comunicação direta é impossível via Libs ou semelhante.

Comment: @RenanValentim atualizei a resposta

Comment: Exatamente, é necessário apenas instalar o Software MGV6 e importar a lista de itens que meu sistema deverá exportar. Editei minha pergunta com as informações de onde encontrar a documentação completa.